# Передача элемента двумерного массива в функцию по указателю

Tags: c++, qt, указатели

Никак не могу передать элемент двумерного массива в функцию. Не могу понять, что именно не правильно: все примеры искал в гугле, но у меня почему-то нечего не работает:

```
QWidget widget[MAX_ELEMENT][MAX_ELEMENT];  
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENT; i++)
      for(int j = 0; j < MAX_ELEMENT; j++)
      {
          //Здесь хочу передать элемент массива в метод, но компилятор ругается на несоответствие типов
          connect(*((*(+i))+j)), SIGNAL(mySignal()), this, SLOT(mySlot());
          //Пробовал так, не помогает 
          //connect((*widget+i)[j], SIGNAL(mySignal()), this, SLOT(mySlot());
          //и так тоже
          //connect(*(*widget+i)[j], SIGNAL(mySignal()), this, SLOT(mySlot());
      }
```

Сигнатура функции:

```
connect(const QObject * sender, const char * signal, const QObject * receiver, const char * method, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)
```

Answer (score 5):

Нет никакого смысла использовать арифметику указателей - просто пишите так:

```
connect(&widget[i][j], SIGNAL(mySignal()), this, SLOT(mySlot());
```

Это раз. Ну а если уж очень хочется именно с указателями, тогда нужно писать так:

```
connect(&*(*(widget  + i) + j), SIGNAL(mySignal()), this, SLOT(mySlot());
```

Кстати, когда соединяете сигнал со слотом, который находится в текущем классе, тогда `this` можно опустить:

```
connect(&widget[i][j], SIGNAL(mySignal()), SLOT(mySlot());
```

Но помните, что Вы передали в `connect` указатель на элемент локального массива и если у Вас в коде так же, то  никаких сигналов Вы не увидите, т.к. по окончании функции все виджеты будут удалены и сигнал, соответственно, не будут никогда сгенерированы.

Comment: `&widget[i][j]` `widget[i]+j`

Comment: @Qwertiy, на мой взгляд, синтаксис взятия адреса лучше отражает, тот факт, что нам нужно передать указатель. Поэтому я не стал делать "кратко" - в этом просто нет нужды, а читаемость теряется.